# PMD find literal string in Android code

Tags: java, android, localization, internationalization, pmd

How can I restrict developers to NOT use `string literals` and use `R.string` when needed in Android Project. I heard PMD rules but not familiar of it, any guide please or any test can work to check if there is not litreal used.
Thank you

Comment: I am not sure if that idea is really helpful. I guess you are **only** concerned about strings that are shown to the user, because those require internationalization?! So, not every string literal in your app source would be a problem then.

Comment: True, we are more concerned to displayable text but it would be nice to know if there is any Literal in project